# HapiJS Route Return Response From Request

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, request, hapi.js

I am using the request module and am making a successful request. I get the response back but I can not figure out how to return this response back to my route to return to my client.

My route:

```
'use strict';

const displayBuild = require('../lib/display-build');

module.exports = {
    method: ['PUT', 'POST'],
    path: '/displayBuild',
    handler: function(request, h) {
        console.log('Displaying build config...');
        console.log(request.payload)
        try {
            displayBuild(request, h);
            console.log("h:", h)
            return {'success': 201}
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return {'ERR': err}
        }
    }
};
```

displayBuild function:

```
var request = require('request');
var URL = "url"

const displayBuild = function (req, res) {
    var options = {
        uri: URL,
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            "content-type": "application/json"
        },
        json: req.payload
    };
    request(options, function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            console.log('success')
        } else {
            console.log('ERROR:', error)
            throw error
        }
        return body;
    });
}

module.exports = displayBuild;
```

Obviously `return body` is not enough.

I would like to return the body back to my route and return that back as the response to my client.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

I solved it myself by using async and await functionality. What I did was made the handler function an async function

```
async (request, h) => {
...
var body = await displayBuild(...)
}
```

and returned a new Promise from the displayBuild function.

Message me if anyone wants lower level explanation.